# <Windows>Why does std::thread::native_handle return a value of type 'long long unsigned int' instead of void* (a.k.a. HANDLE)?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, msys

I need to suspend a thread on windows via Windows SDK on msys.
I tried something like

```
std::thread thread(somefunction, someparameters);
HANDLE handle=thread.native_handle();
SuspendThread(handle);
```

But gcc told me the return value of native_handle() is 'long long unsigned int' but not void*.
So I tried

```
HANDLE handle=reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(thread.native_handle());
```

But it does not work because when I called **GetLastError()** I received the error code 6 which means the  handle is invalid.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned "handle" is the thread *id* not the `HANDLE` as returned by [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread).

You need to use [`OpenThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) to get a handle from the id.

Comment: The returned "handle" is only compatible with `pthread.h`?

Comment: @Soha "Pthread" is the *POSIX* thread system, unrelated to the Windows thread system.

Comment: @Soha No, you just need to call `OpenThread()` to retrieve a useful (Win32) handle from the "handle" (in fact thread ID) returned by `native_handle()`.

Comment: I suppose this is specific to Msys, in which case the tags on the question should be updated to reflect it. Microsoft's C++ library is documented to return an actual [native handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#native_handle), not a TID.

Comment: @ErykSun Missed that MSYS bit (indeed it should be in the tag list, but the mention of `gcc` should have been a hint though). On the other hand, the type doesn't fit with the documented `DWORD` type of the Windows TID. As you say, it might be a MSYS specific "handle", and then maybe even `OpenThread` won't work.